# Spring boot and Tomcat handling users

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

So I am building a web app with java spring boot, and tomcat, and I am stuck trying to figure out how to have multiple users, with their separate accounts on this web app at the same time. My current problem is that once I am logged in with the second account, device with the first account becomes second account. So at the end, both devices have a second account on them.... is there anything special I need to do in order for this to work? I am pretty new to all this.

Comment: Define **device**. If you mean single browser multiple tabs, that isn't going to work. If you mean seperate browsers, you have done something wrong in your application and storing state in place you shouldn't be storing state.

Comment: Yea, i have multiple browsers.

Comment: Then the issue is on your side and you are keeping state in places you shouldnt be keeping state. Also you shouldn't be rolling your own security solution but use something like Spring Security.

Comment: Can you tell me where am i supposed to store state?

Comment: You shouldn't, that is the whole point. If anything it should be in the user session but that is it. BUt as stated use a proven solution like Spring Security, Apache Shiro, instead of trying to build your own,

Comment: And if i want each user to have its personal account? And depending on their profile to have diferent output.

Comment: You still don't store state. Your controller shold act upon that based on the current user. You don't store the user in the controller. Again as stated use something like Spring Security, Apache Shiro which integrate with Spring, which make this a breeze.

Comment: oh ok, so if i understood correctly i am supposed to use something like spring security to store current user?  And i am not supposed to store user in controler class?

Comment: You don't have to use Spring Security, you can also store the user in the HttpSession yourself and retrieve it again. However building a proper and secure, security framework is a complex task, so better to use a proven solution.

Comment: OK, so you think that something that will be easiest to integrate and to learn will be something like spring security and apache shiro. And what would you recommend beginner to use?

Comment: Just use Spring Security.